# How to view conda config paths?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I was running some tests and ran the line below not realizing this was a global action.

```bash
conda env config vars set <my_var>=<value>
```

I continued to use this moving forward:

```bash
conda env config vars set <my_var>=<value> -n <name of my env>
```

But now I can't unset the variable I accidently set globally and it's becoming the default for the rest of my environments. In `./envs/conda-meta/state`, I can view all of the environment configurations I've set for that environment. Is there an equivalent to this for your **base** (default) environment? I'm just looking for the file where it gets saved to so I can remove the config, but the Conda documentation doesn't tell me this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **base** environment also should have a `conda-meta/state`. But you can also use the `unset` subcommand:

#### Documentation

```bash
$ conda env config vars -h
usage: conda-env config vars [-h] {list,set,unset} ...

Interact with environment variables associated with Conda environments

Options:

positional arguments:
  {list,set,unset}
    list            List environment variables for a conda environment
    set             Set environment variables for a conda environment
    unset           Unset environment variables for a conda environment

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        Show this help message and exit.

examples:
    conda env config vars list -n my_env
    conda env config vars set MY_VAR=something OTHER_THING=ohhhhya
    conda env config vars unset MY_VAR
```

#### Usage

That is, doing something like

```bash
conda env config vars unset <my_var> -n base
```

would be far preferable than manually editing the `conda-meta/state` file.